# Can adding default parameters to a library function break the import or useage?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

In creating a shared library, I must implement the function `void foo();`  foo() has dependencies that I would like to mock in my unit tests. My initial thought is to rewrite the signature to include default parameters so that I can inject the dependencies.

One option is to use foo() as a wrapper around bar() and write unit tests for bar() like so:

```
void bar(SomeClass *someObject=NULL);  // test this   
void foo() { 
    bar(); 
}
```

However, my question is how safe is it to modify foo() to take default parameters without breaking the library import or usage of foo()?

I can do things with the processor to rewrite the signature depending on build settings(test, debug, release); however, the question still remains. I can't recall how C++ implements default parameters under the hood.

Comment: Any declarations and definitions **must be compiled consistently** to be sure that interfaces aren't broken.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that default parameters are specified at the declaration (unless the function is inlined):

```
void foo(int i, const char* p=nullptr);

void foo(int i, const char* p) {
    //...
}
```

The responsibility for populating the default parameters falls to the caller: https://godbolt.org/g/8z63qA

Under the hood, the function signature is that of a function with a full set of arguments, so these two functions have the same signature:

```
void foo(int i, const char* p);
void foo(int i, const char* p=nullptr);
```

8.3.5/8 [dcl.fct](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct)

> The return type, the parameter-type-list, the ref-qualifier, the cv-qualifier-seq, and whether the function has a non-throwing exception-specification, but not the default arguments ([dcl.fct.default]) or the exception specification ([except.spec]), are part of the function type.

So adding a default parameter to your function will change its signature and require that clients be recompiled with the new header.